Binding Issue in MAUI CollectionView: Property "FileName" Not Found in DataContext
I am working on a .NET MAUI application and am having trouble binding a property in a CollectionView. Specifically, I am trying to display a list of uploaded files and their filenames, but I am encountering an issue where the FileName property is not recognized in the CollectionView.
Here’s an overview of my setup and the problem I’m facing:
ViewModel:
I have a UserProfileMauiViewModel that includes an ObservableCollection:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using webapplib.Client.Services;
using webapp.worktime.Client.ClientApi;
using webapp.worktime.Client.Services;
using webapp.worktime.Client.ViewModel;
using webapplib.Shared.Data;
using webapplib.Shared.Model;
using Deploy.WorkTime.MAUI.Services;



namespace Deploy.WorkTime.MAUI.ViewModel;
public partial class UserProfileMauiViewModel : UserProfileViewModel {

    private readonly IFileUploadService _fileUploadService;
    public ObservableCollection<FileData> UploadedFiles { get; }
    public UserProfileMauiViewModel(
        AppDataService appData,
        IExtraDataService extraData,
        IPageNavigator pageNavigator,
        WorkersClientApi workersClientApi,
        IStorageService storageService,
        SalaryService salaryService,
         IFileUploadService fileUploadService)
        : base(appData, extraData, pageNavigator, workersClientApi, storageService, salaryService) {
        _fileUploadService = fileUploadService;
        UploadedFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileData>();
        UploadFileCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(UploadFileAsync);
        RemoveFileCommand = new RelayCommand<FileData?>(RemoveFile);

    }
    public IAsyncRelayCommand UploadFileCommand { get; }
    public IRelayCommand<FileData> RemoveFileCommand { get; }

    private async Task UploadFileAsync()
    {
        var (files, emptyFiles, bigFiles) = await _fileUploadService.UploadFilesAsync();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            UploadedFiles.Add(file);
            
        }
    }
    private void RemoveFile(FileData? file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            UploadedFiles.Remove(file);
        }
    }

XAML Page:
In my XAML page, I am trying to bind to the UploadedFiles collection:
<pages:WorkTimePage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
                    xmlns:material="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material"
                    xmlns:uranium="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui"
                    xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Camera.MAUI;assembly=Camera.MAUI"
                    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Deploy.WorkTime.MAUI.Pages"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Deploy.WorkTime.MAUI.Views"
                    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Deploy.WorkTime.MAUI.ViewModel"
                    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:webapplib.MAUI.Converters;assembly=webapplib.MAUI"
                    xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:webapplib.Client.Resources;assembly=webapplib.Client"
                    x:Class="Deploy.WorkTime.MAUI.Pages.UserProfilePage"
                    x:TypeArguments="viewmodel:UserProfileMauiViewModel"
                    x:DataType="viewmodel:UserProfileMauiViewModel"
                    Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- Define converters and styles here -->
            <converters:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
     <VerticalStackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="10">
     <Grid Margin="20" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource SomeBackgroundColor}" ColumnSpacing="10" RowSpacing="10">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <Button Text="Upload Identification File"
         Command="{Binding UploadFileCommand}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

         <Label Text="Uploaded Files:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
         <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding UploadedFiles}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
             <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <Grid Padding="5" ColumnSpacing="10">
                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                             <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                         <!-- Binding to FileData properties -->
                         <Label Text="{**Binding FileName**}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                         <Button Text="Remove" 
         Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:UserProfileMauiViewModel}}, Path=RemoveFileCommand}" 
         CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
         Grid.Column="1" />
                     </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         </CollectionView>
     </Grid>
 </VerticalStackLayout>

Issue
The FileName property is not found in the data context. I have verified that FileData has a FileName property and that the UploadedFiles collection is correctly populated.
I think the problem comes from the idea that the page has x:DataType="viewmodel:UserProfileMauiViewModel"
and the collectionView bind to public ObservableCollection UploadedFiles
FileData class inherited from FileBaseData and IFileData and this is FileBaseData -
public record class FileBaseData : FileKeyData, IEntityKeyNameDataClient, IRemovedData {
    public string FileName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsRemoved { get; set; }
    public string GetEntityName() => FileName;
    public string GetDisplayName() => FileName;
    public FileBaseData() { }
    public FileBaseData(FileBaseData item) : base(item) {
        FileName = item.FileName;
        CreationTime = item.CreationTime;
        IsRemoved = item.IsRemoved;
    }
}

while searching for a solution, I saw someone suggest adding  but it didn't work.
I don't know if it matters but UserProfileViewModel is a viewModel in a Blazor project and I building a Maui project so far it didn't interrupted me.

To resolve the issue, I added the correct XML namespace for the FileBaseData class in the XAML file and updated the CollectionView to correctly bind to the FileName property.
First, add the namespace for FileBaseData:
XML:
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:webapplib.Shared.Data;assembly=webapplib.Shared"

Then, update the CollectionView in the XAML to bind to the FileName property:
XML:
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding UploadedFiles}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:FileBaseData">
            <Label Text="{Binding FileName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

This ensures that the FileBaseData type is recognized and the FileName property can be bound correctly in the CollectionView.
By adding the appropriate namespace and specifying the x:DataType for the DataTemplate, the binding to the FileName property works as expected.

Add the x:DataType="models:FileData" attribute to the DataTemplate inside of the CollectionView. And make sure to add xmlns:models="webapplib.Shared.Model" (this is an assumption here that this is the correct namespace based on the code you provided, it might be different) to the root page.
Inside of a DataTemplate the scope changes from your page view model, to just the model that is 1 object inside of your collection that you use as the ItemsSource.

i add xmlns:models="webapplib.Shared.Data" to the pages:WorkTimePage
and add

and the error -Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error XLS0414 The type 'models:FileBaseData' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. Deploy.WorkTime.MAUI  192

I don't have your full code. Make sure you're using the right model. Looking at your code again that should probably be FileData

this is the namespace where FileBaseData and FileData are located:
namespace webapplib.Shared.Data;
and after adding xmlns:models="webapplib.Shared.Data"
and  
still 'models:FileData' was not found and
Error (active) XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "webapplib.Shared.Data:FileData".
